# Greengrass discovery Demo Application is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, freertos, ca

I have two STM32 Discovery kit (as recommended by AWS), I want to connect them to Greengrass group using Amazon FreeRTOS. I went through the documentation about Amazon FreeRTOS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/freertos/latest/userguide/gg-demo.html) and Greengrass demo.
I add Thing, Certificates and policies according to description in tutorial and add the thing to greengrass group. Also I downloaded "Greengrass discovery for ST " from software section of AWS console, update the wifi username and password, iot endpoint in "aws_clientcredentials.h" and also update the certificates on "aws_clientcredentials_keys.h".
According to documentation, subscribing to "freertos/demos/ggd" topic will give some message to IoT test, but it is not the case.
Does anybody have same experience?

Output of the console is:

```
0 0  Starting key provisioning...
1 3  Write root certificate...
2 7  Write device private key...
3 15  Write device certificate...
4 23  Key provisioning done...
5 608  WiFi module initialized.
6 4010  WiFi connected to AP defabe Engineering_EXT.
7 4015  IP Address acquired 192.168.178.50
8 4020  Attempting automated selection of Greengrass device
9 34517  About to close socket.
10 34756  Socket closed.
11 34759  JSON parsing: Couldn't find certificate
12 34764  Auto-connect: Failed to retrieve Greengrass address and certificate.
```

Any help and advise would be really appreciated.
Regards,
Keivan

P.S: I've created a Greengrass group with core and successful deployment.

Comment: I used also curl to get information but the result is "resource not found", but there is thing in aws iot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
There are 2 important thing that cause this issue:
1- Under greengrass setting "Automatically detect and override connection information" should be activated.
2- The policy attached to device can cause this problem. It should contain:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "greengrass:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
      "*"
    ]
}
```

It needs the correct resource and action.

Answer (score 0):

You don't explicitly say in your question that you've [created a Greengrass Core](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-gs.html), and completed at least one successful [configuration deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/configs-core.html) to it after having added your AWS IoT "Thing" to the Greengrass group. Those are prerequisites to the demo app you're trying to run.

Once you've done the above, I recommend that you use the debugging steps in the Advanced Diagnostics section of the [README.md for the Amazon FreeRTOS Greengrass Connectivity demo app](https://github.com/aws/amazon-freertos/blob/master/demos/common/greengrass_connectivity/README.md). Synopsis: those steps confirm the configuration and trust between your AWS IoT “Thing” and your Greengrass Core using the [AWS command-line interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli).

If you're able to do an MQTT connect and subscribe to the AWS IoT broker without the server disconnecting you, that's conclusive that your Amazon FreeRTOS device has a valid client certificate and at least a basic policy attached to it. But, among other things, the Advanced Diagnostics steps above will help you confirm whether your Thing certificate policy is sufficient for the Greengrass demo. In any case, I suspect that your problem is Greengrass deployment related at this point.

Comment: Thanks for comments and help. 
Actually I went through the [link](https://github.com/aws/amazon-freertos/blob/master/demos/common/greengrass_connectivity/README.md), 
I can confirm that I got correct information in all sections. I've also used Greengrass Discovery RESTful API for retrieving ggca using curl command:

curl --cert 9776525867-certificate.pem.crt --key 9776525867-private.key https://[endpoint]:8443/greengrass/discover/thing/[DeviceName]

but output is:
{"message":null,"traceId":"acc7de31-d0f4-0321-d9ad-54e8f4c84127"}.
any help and idea would be really appreciated.

Comment: As you mentioned in your comment, I tested the connection of board with AWS IoT broker and I can subscribe to the example topic mentioned in document ("freertos/demos/echo"). So the certificates are valid. When I switch to "Connect to AWS Greengrass - ST" FreeRTOS software, then the board can not do greengrass discovery.  It means the problem is from greengrass part. I used Python sdk for creating greengrass core and group and I can do successful deployment. Is there any other settings or something? as mentioned I can't retrieve ggca with curl as well.